# Only show meta on one post type on search results page

Tags: post-meta, search, post-type

I want to remove the post meta from all post types that are *not* "posts" from my site or at least from the search results.

Im currently using the Jnews theme and in the search results page I get all post types (posts, pages, products) but I'm only interested in leaving the post meta (.jeg_post_meta) for posts and removing it for all other post types like pages, products and others that the results page can bring.

`.jeg_post_meta` is the style class that the search results page is using for all meta from all post types.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any of the output code for the search results output, so what I've provided below is a guess based on how things 'should' work - chances are things will look different in your theme so you'll need to sort out how to apply the same logic.

In your search results template (`content-search.php` maybe?) you'll have your search results pulled in and they'll all be in a variable like so:

```
$search_query
```

That'll be the results of the search query (may be named something different)...

So in your `while()` loop you'll want to check get the 'type' for each result:

```
$type = $search_query->post->post_type;
```

Then before you output the HTML and data for the post meta, you'll check to see if the type matches `post`, like so:

```
if( $type == 'post' ) :
  //your post meta output code
endif;
```

Putting the whole thing together... and remember, lots of guesswork in here:

```
<?php
    while( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
        $search_query->the_post();
        $type = $search_query->post->post_type;
        the_title();
        if( $type == 'post' ) :
            echo '<div class="jeg_post_meta">';
                echo 'By ' . the_author_posts_link() . 'on ' . the_time( 'F jS, Y' ) . 'in ' . the_category( ', ' ) . '.';
            echo '</div>';
        endif;
        echo '<div class="jeg_post_content">';
            the_excerpt();
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Just a reminder though that you shouldn't be editing a third-party theme because your edits will get lost if/when it updates and you'll have to start over.  So you want to do this in a child theme where you're overriding existing templates and content parts.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for not providing the output code, first time using this site for asking a question.

I tried to search for something close to the content-search.php but only found 3 files that could match the description. 

search.php
searcharchive.php
search-result.php

Comment: It'd be `search-result.php` and you may also need to do `searcharchive.php`, but you should be able to skip over `search.php` as that is most likely just the actual search itself or a 'search page'. (Oh, and no need to apologize, we're all here to help one another, I was just pointing it out so that you didn't expect to find the exact same thing.)